# Is there a best way to get data from snowflake to s3

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, attunity, snowflake-schema

Is there a best way to get data from snowflake to s3. ? the data snowflake shows will be in s3, but we don't have access to that bucket.  And we only need to get the specific tables from Snowflake not the entire data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). The use of the word "best" will cause some people to view this as an opinion based question which can get the question closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you will want the [unloading into Amazon S3](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-unload-s3.html) documentation.

you can ether choose a table with the

```
copy into s3://mybucket/unload/
  from mytable
  storage_integration = myint
  file_format = (format_name = my_csv_format);
```

or choose from a select, which is mostly how I export data.

```
copy into @my_stage
from (
    select * from orderstiny limit 5
);
```

again the [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html)  doc's are helpful here.

Comment: What does `COPY INTO` command returns? I mean how do we know if copy is success?

Answer (score 2):

You can use COPY INTO command for both data load as well as data unload from source to destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of the [options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html). The option1 is the most secure of them. If it is for internal or inside vpc communication then option3 could the easier one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome in stackoverflow @ameya-bapat ! Please, describe briefly the recommended option here in your answer. If the hyperlink will not work in the future, then your answer will be useless without additional info.